# TailwindCSS in Create-React-App project, error requires PostCSS 8

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I was given a `create-react-app` project with Tailwind in it, initially it was installed with the compatibility version for PostCSS 7 as per the official guide https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation#building-your-css :

```
npm install tailwindcss@npm:@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat @tailwindcss/postcss7-compat postcss@^7 autoprefixer@^9
```

This installed:

```
"autoprefixer": "^9.8.8",
"postcss": "^7.0.39",
"tailwindcss": "npm:@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat@^2.2.17"
```

Then, when trying to build the css, with:

```
tailwind build -i src/app/styles/tailwind.css -o src/app/styles/base.css
```

It gives the error:

```
node_modules\tailwindcss\peers\index.js:91395
    throw new Error('PostCSS plugin ' + plugin.postcssPlugin + ' requires PostCSS 8.\n' 
+ 'Migration guide for end-users:\n' + 'https://github.com/postcss/postcss/wiki/PostCSS-8-for-end-users');
          ^
Error: PostCSS plugin tailwindcss requires PostCSS 8.
Migration guide for end-users:
https://github.com/postcss/postcss/wiki/PostCSS-8-for-end-users
```

So, then I have tried the other way, with updating tailwind, postcss and everything along with a `craco` config, again following the official guides:

```
npm install tailwindcss@latest postcss@latest autoprefixer@latest
```

Also installed `craco` as per the guide and  created  `craco.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
  style: {
    postcss: {
      plugins: [
        require('tailwindcss'),
        require('autoprefixer'),
      ],
    },
  },
}
```

Doing it this way, building the css with:

```
tailwind build -i src/app/styles/tailwind.css -o src/app/styles/base.css
```

Is working, but then when I try to start the project with `npm run craco start` it fails to compile:

```
Failed to compile.

./node_modules/react-widgets/styles.css (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--5-oneOf-4-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./node_modules/react-widgets/styles.css)
Error: PostCSS plugin tailwindcss requires PostCSS 8.

Failed to compile.

./node_modules/react-widgets/styles.css (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--5-oneOf-4-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./node_modules/react-widgets/styles.css)
Error: PostCSS plugin tailwindcss requires PostCSS 8.
Migration guide for end-users:
https://github.com/postcss/postcss/wiki/PostCSS-8-for-end-users
```

So I am stuck in a situation where I can either compile the project, but not the css, or compile the css, but not the project.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to complete a build by installing the following packages, copied from the TailwindCSS docs:

`npm install -D tailwindcss@npm:@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat postcss@^7 autoprefixer@^9`

https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/create-react-app

From what I've found, create-react-app does not support PostCSS 8 yet, see:

- https://github.com/postcss/postcss/wiki/PostCSS-8-for-end-users
- https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/pull/9716